# ASP.NET ERR: Master Page does not exist

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, iis-7.5, master-pages

In my asp.net web application, I have three layers such as PresentationLayer, BussinessLogicLayer and DataAccessLayer. I have a master.master, login.aspx and Default.aspx files in the application root directory.

In the Presentation Layer, I have a web page called Tracking.aspx. I have included the master page in the page directory like below:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" MasterPageFile="~/Master.Master" CodeBehind="Tracking.aspx.cs" Inherits="mysite.PresentationLayer.Tracking" Title="Tracking" %>
```

When build and running the application in the local system, it works fine. After hosting it in the `IIS 7.5`, it throws the below error when I click the page Tracking.aspx;

> The file '/mysite/PresentationLayer/Master.Master' does not exist.

I have included the master page in the Default.aspx too. But it is working fine in the IIS.

I know the problem is giving the master page in the masterpagefile attribute. But don't know how to give. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Is `Default.aspx` in the same folder as `Tracking.aspx`?

Comment: No. It is in the application root directory as like master page.

Answer (score 0):

This this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" MasterPageFile="../Master.Master" CodeBehind="Tracking.aspx.cs" Inherits="mysite.PresentationLayer.Tracking" Title="Tracking" %>
```

IIS is looking in the same directory as your page for the master file, because that's what your old masterpagefile attribute told it to do. The above code should get it to go up one level of the file tree, then look for it.

Comment: Specifying relative paths to the master page probably isn't a good idea. Paths should be root relative.

Comment: Yes. I tried like this. But it gives the error "The virtual path '/mysite/Master.Master' maps to another application, which is not allowed."

Comment: @mason Yeah, it's a pretty awful idea, but that sort of stuff can be useful for debugging.

Comment: In which case, you should post that as a comment and not an answer.

Comment: I'd rather start with the debugging step, then edit it as the problem gets solved. That way, future viewers see the process and learn more than the answer -they pick up something about how debugging goes.

Comment: @MichaelMcPherson You can describe the debugging steps in your post, but lack of an answer in your post doesn't make it okay. Use comments to get more information or suggest debugging steps.